# How can I output an array in "popular" and "alphabetical" order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, arraylist

```js
     groupBrands: [
        {
          latter: "A",
          brands: [
            {
              id: 'ac',
              title: 'AC',
              image: ''
            },
            {
              id: 'acura',
              title: 'Acura',
              image: '/images/acura.svg'
            },
           
          ]
        },
        {
          latter: "B",
          brands: [
            {
              id: 'BAW',
              title: 'BAW',
              image: '/images/baw.svg'
            },
            {
              id: 'Bentley',
              title: 'Bentley',
              image: ''
            },
          ]
        },
]
```

```html
      <ul>
          <li v-for="groupBrand in groupBrands"
              :key="groupBrand.latter"
              class="group"
          >
            <h3>{{ groupBrand.latter }}</h3>
            <ul>
              <li v-for="brand in groupBrand.brands"
                  :key="brand.title"
              >
                <label :for="brand.id">
                  <input
                      type="radio"
                      :id="brand.id"
                      name="brand"
                  >
                  <span>{{ brand.title }}</span>
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
</ul>
```

*How can I output an array in "popular" and "alphabetical" order? In this example, I show it in alphabetical order, but I do not know how to display the "popular" ones that have an image*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbb7e.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhxrC.png)

Comment: Strictly speaking you do not display it in alphabetical order right now but you simply display it in the order the array is in. The fact that that is alphabetical is only coincidental. What you generally need to do is sort (and filter) the array according to whatever logic you want, alphabetical, popularity, string length, whatever and then display that sorted array.

Comment: You'd better need a property to contain `popular` score in order to make a sort